# Distributing problem using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

> For $r\in\mathbb{Z^*}$, let $a_r$ denote the number of ways to distribute $r$ identical objects into $3$ identical boxes, $b_r$ be the number of distributions so that the boxes are to be non-empty, and $c_r$ be the number of distributions such that the box containing the least number of objects has an even number of objects. Hence, find the generating functions for $\left(a_r\right)$, $\left(b_r\right)$ and $\left(c_r\right)$.

**ATTEMPT**

The number of ways to distribute $r$ identical objects into $3$ identical boxes is equivalent to the number of partitions of the integer $r$ into at most $3$ parts, which in turn equals to the number of partitions of $r$ such that the largest part is less than or equal to $3$. Hence, we have the following generating function for $\left(a_r\right)$
\begin{align}
&\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^3+x^6+\cdots\right)\\
=&\dfrac{1}{1-x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-x^3}
\end{align}
Suppose the boxes have to be non-empty, then we have to find the number of partitions of $r$ such that the largest part is equal to $3$. Hence, we have the following generating function for $\left(b_r\right)$
\begin{align}
&\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots\right)\left(x^3+x^6+\cdots\right)\\
=&\dfrac{1}{1-x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\dfrac{x^3}{1-x^3}
\end{align}
I'm stuck with finding the generating function for $\left(c_r\right)$, I know the answer is
\begin{align}
&\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^6+x^{12}+\cdots\right)\\
=&\dfrac{1}{1-x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-x^6}
\end{align}
but I don't really know the reasoning behind it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Drawing Ferrers diagram, (c) is equivalent to asking how many partitions are there such that there is an even number of columns with three dots, hence giving the solution.