# Distributing identical objects into identical boxes using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

> For $r \in \mathbb{N}$, let $a_r$ denote the number of ways to distribute $r$ identical objects into 3 identical boxes so that the box with the fewest objects has an odd number of objects. Find a generating function for $(a_r)$.

There was a similar question posted 6 years ago, but it had no replies:
[Distributing problem using generating functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574057/distributing-problem-using-generating-functions).

Any hints/help in understanding the solution would be appreciated!

Comment: Drawing Ferrers diagram, (c) is equivalent to asking how many partitions are there such that there is an odd number of columns with three dots, hence giving the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Building on your work in the earlier question, you need to have an odd number of 3s in the conjugate partition.  So that factor in the generating function is
$$ x^3 + x^9 + x^{15} + \cdots = x^3(1 + x^6 + x^{12} + \cdots) = \frac{x^3}{1-x^6}$$
giving, altogether, 
$$ \sum_{n \ge 0} a(n) x^n = \prod_{i \ge 1} \frac{1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2} \cdot \frac{x^3}{1-x^6}. $$